# Starting with Java web Spring framework what is #{bundle.CreateSaveLink}?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new with Java Web development.
Can someone explain to me what is this marked in yellow color.
What means bundle,[image] what is his purpose and where is he located and can I change this definition on my own way?
.

Comment: Where is spring and spring mvc in picture  ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a value coming from an object that was used as a model.
Probably you have a java class annotated as @Controller, having a method annotated with @RequestMapping, mapping to a url that renders this html.
Inside this method, you will find the code creating a model object, and setting it on a map, which key is "bundle".
Basically, this yellow code will invoke the getCreateInspectorateSaveLink() method and set this element value attribute with the result.

I say probably, because there is some ways to accomplish that, and the one I described is the most common.

All this resources you can find more info, searching for "Spring MVC".

Here you can find some example: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-and-list-example/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like part of a JSF page.
Is it a xhtml file?

Check this video: https://youtu.be/6Xj3UUuPBDk?t=11m6s

h:commandLink creates a JSF button.
#{bundle.CreateSaveLink} is the Display text of the button, and on clicking the button the create method of inspectorateController gets called.

Bundle is probably a resource file from which the key CreateSaveLink is taken and its value is displayed.

Example:
Bundle.properties file contains a line:
...
CreateSaveLink=Create
...